# Pass custom context to Django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework.
All models in my app contain User field and I want to write to this field link to current user.
How can I pass user object to model?
I've tired to write User link in SerializerClass, but I think it's not the best solution.

In view:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(created_by=self.user)
```

Model:

```
class Tracker(models.Model):
    serial_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
```

Comment: Please share your current code.

Comment: I've shared code

Comment: What do you mean by passing `user` object to model?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to. DRF can do that for you.
[As here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#request-objects).

Since you haven't shared your complete code I am inclined to share a VERY SIMPLE implementation without writing a lot of code yourself and relying on DRF's ability is:

```
from rest_framework import generics
class MyView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Tracker.objects
    serializer_class = TrackerSerializer #Assuming that this is your serializer

    def post(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        return self.create(request , *args , **kwargs)
```

DRF will itself take care of the relationships. This code works assuming that you have [authenticaton](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/) set up and thus `request.user` is not an `Anonymous User`.

Answer (score 0):

To grab the logged in user from a generic view, you should use `self.request.user`:

In view:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```